# How to understand multiplicity $N_{ij}^{k}$ in general fusion rules in conformal field theories?

Tags: conformal-field-theory, representation-theory

I cannot quite understand the fusion rules in conformal field theories: 
\begin{eqnarray}
\phi_i\times\phi_j=N_{ij}^{k}\phi_k,
\end{eqnarray}
where the coefficient $N_{ij}^{k}$ according to textbooks can take general nonnegative integers. I cannot quite understand why that $N_{ij}^{k}$ is larger than 1 is meaningful. Since $N_{ij}^{k}$ is nonzero as long as
\begin{eqnarray}
\langle\phi_k\phi_i\phi_j\rangle\neq0, 
\end{eqnarray}
the specific value $N_{ij}^{k}$ seems meaningless.

Comment: You should provide additional  context on what the $\phi_k$ are, what fusion rules are etc so that your question is a little more self-contained.

Comment: Hi Smart Yao: Is your real question why the fusion structure constants $N_{ij}^{k}$ (after appropriate normalization) is integer-valued?

Comment: @Qmechanic I was simply confused the mathematical meaning of larger-than-1 $N_{ij}^k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the decomposition of a tensor product of two representation $\Gamma_1\otimes \Gamma_2$ (take them to be irreducible for simplicity) will result in a sum of irreducible representations
$$
\Gamma_1\otimes \Gamma_2 = \sum_k N_{12}^k \Gamma_k\, . \tag{1}
$$
Eq.(1) is called the Clebsch-Gordan series.  A particular irrep $\Gamma_k$ can generically occur more than once.  How many times an irrep occurs depends on $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$.

As an example, suppose $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$ are both the 2-dimensional $\{2,1\}$ irrep of $S_3$.  Then $\Gamma_1\otimes \Gamma_2$ is a 4-dimensional reducible representation which can, by elementary use of character orthogonality, be written as
$$
\{2,1\}\otimes\{2,1\}=\{3\}\oplus\{2,1\}\oplus\{1,1,1\} \tag{2}
$$
so in this *specific* example the various $N^{\{\lambda\}}_{\{2,1\}\{2,1\}}$s are all $1$.

Looking instead the coupling $\{3,1,1\}\otimes\{3,1,1\}$ of $S_5$ irreps, one finds
\begin{align}
\{3,1,1\}\otimes\{3,1,1\}& = \{5\}\oplus\{4,1\}\oplus 2\{3,2\}\oplus \{3,1,1\}\\
&\quad \oplus 2\{2^21\}\oplus\{21^3\}\oplus \{1^5\}\tag{3}
\end{align}
and you can see that $\{3,2\}$ and $\{2^2,1\}$ actually occur twice in the decomposition.

The same can occur for continuous groups.  Consider the tensor product $(1,1)\otimes(\sigma,\sigma)$ of $SU(3)$ irrep.  One can show using again elementary methods that
\begin{align}
(1,1)\otimes(\sigma,\sigma)&=(\sigma+1,\sigma+1)
\oplus 2(\sigma,\sigma)\\
&\quad \oplus (\sigma-1,\sigma-1)\oplus \hbox{other irreps}\, .
\tag{4}
\end{align}
In this specific example, the irrep $(\sigma,\sigma)$ occurs twice in the decomposition so this particular coefficient $N^{(\sigma,\sigma)}_{(1,1)(\sigma,\sigma)}=2$.

Some observations are in order.  If you think of decomposing the product of two irreps of $SU(2)$, then $N^J_{j_1,j_2}$ is either $0$ or $1$.  For other $SU(n)$, as illustrated in my second example, it may be that some coefficients are greater than $1$.  In general, $N_{ij}^k >1$ will occur when the representations $\Gamma_i$ and $\Gamma_j$ have weight multiplicities.  The problem of constructing the highest weight for irrep $k$ has multiple solutions due to the weight multiplicities.  (In $SU(n)$, both irreps *must* have weight multiplicities, but I'm not sure about other cases.)

In your specific examples, your fields carry a representation of some algebra.  Quoting [this paper by J. Fuchs](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9306162.pdf):

> Fusion rule algebras are certain associative algebras over the complex numbers which arise in various areas of physics and mathematics, where they describe the *possible couplings among three objects out of some given class*.   As examples let me mention:
>
> ....
>
> - *Truncated tensor products of unitary representations of quantum groups* with deformation parameter a root of unity...

[the emphasis is mine] so one can think of the fusion rules are a generalized form of the Clebsch-Gordan series of Eq.(1), as opposed to Eqs.(2), (3) and(4) which are examples of the standard series.

Comment: Pretty nice explanation although a little (but trivial) suggestion on the missed square on l.h.s. of Eq. (2). I have a further question for my specific example of fusion rules in CFT. If $N_{ij}^k>1$, does it mean that it is necessary to have at least $N_{ij}^k$ different primary fields with the same weight $h_k$? In this sense, does it imply nondegeneracy of highest weights in minimal models?

Comment: @SmartYao I'm not an expert in CFT, but the game is counting highest weights.  From a representation theory perspective $N_{ij}^k>1$ means multiple distinct highest weights, irrespective of the degeneracy of weight $h_k$ (this weight might occur multiple times in other irreps where it is not dominant).  Thanks for the heads up on the typo, which is now fixed.

Comment: I now understand the source of this larger-than-one $N_{ij}^k$, but I was wrong in my last comment in that $N_{ij}^k\leq1$ does not mean the nondegeneracy in highest weight.